# Compare-Object remove parts of the resault

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, compareobject

I have code

```
Compare-Object $str $str1 | foreach InputObject | ft -auto | out-file "$resault" -width 5000
```

and I get somthing that looks like this

```
\\Server\path\path\Config.Current.Running.rt-1.ci.cou.txt
```

and i want only some part of it = rt-1.ci.cou in my `$relault` .txt file

Comment: How do you decide what part of it you want?  i.e. What's the rule?  e.g. Is the `\\Server\path\path\Config.Current.Running.` part consistent, or can that vary / is there at least some consistent structure to it?

Comment: Is the first part of your question, where you give code for `compare-object`, etc, relevant, or is the question just: "Given a string such as `\\Server\path\path\Config.Current.Running.rt-1.ci.cou.txt` how do I reduce it to `rt-1.ci.cou`?)

Answer (score 0):

```
#Set a variable, Path, with the full string you're looking at
[string]$Path = '\\Server\path\path\Config.Current.Running.rt-1.ci.cou.txt' 

#Remove the directory so we're left with just the filename
[string]$Filename = (Split-Path -Path $Path -Leaf)
#$FileName: Config.Current.Running.rt-1.ci.cou.txt

#use regular expressions to capture the text that appears after the 3rd period (`.`) and before the last period.
$Filename -replace '^[^.]*\.[^.]*\.[^.]*\.(.*)\.[^.]*$', '$1'
#Output: rt-1.ci.cou
```